# Guessing Game Logic

Tags: java

I am trying to create a game where the AI is trying to guess the number the user is thinking through a series of questions.

Example:

```
Is your number greater than 50? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 25? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 38? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 44? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 41? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 43? (y/n)
y
The number you're thinking of is 44.
```

I understand you have to set a new upperLimit and lowerLimit based on what the user enters and then return the average of the new limits. My code does not work well.

What my code does if I'm thinking of the number 59.

```
Is your number greater than 50? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 75? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 62? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 56? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 59? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 57? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 58? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 58? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 58? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 58? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 58? (y/n)
```

Any advice/tips/help is greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
public void play(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    instructions(lowerLimit, upperLimit);

    while (lowerLimit != upperLimit) {
        if(isGreaterThan(average(lowerLimit, upperLimit))) {
            lowerLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        } else {
            upperLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number you're thinking of is " + lowerLimit);
}

public boolean isGreaterThan(int value) {
    System.out.println("Is your number greater than " + value + "? (y/n)");
    String answer = reader.nextLine();
    return answer.equals("y");
}

public int average(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    return (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2;
}
```

Comment: `my code kind of works but not quite` - It either works or doesn't work. If it doesn't work, what doesn't work?

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see where the code's not going what you expect, then fix it.  If you have a programming problem then be sure to post it here with a clear description of what's not working.

Comment: I updated the main post with what my code does, I'm not too sure how to explain this so I apologise.

Comment: Afaik, your AI thinks it's greater than 59 since you told it it was when it actually is 59. That's probably a case to handle.

Comment: The output you get should be enough to find the flaw in your logic. Ask yourself, in the last step, what is your upper limit, what is your lower limit, what is the average between them, which value are you updating and, based on this, why isn't your loop stopping (and does it need to continue?)? Once you know where you go wrong, you should probably think what the new limits should be given some limits and rewrite your logic based on that.

Comment: I see the flaw but I'm just having a mind blank on what I need to do to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this lowerLimit = average(lowerLimit, upperLimit) + 1;

The explanation is very simple. The question you're always asking is if the number is greater than X. If it is, X+1 should become the lower limit, because obviously the number can't be X. The same can't be applied in the other end of the interval, because if your number is X, the answer to the question is it greater is No, so the upperLimit should stay X.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to

```
return (firstNumber + secondNumber) / 2;
```

This is using integer division, so when `firstNumber = 58` and `secondNumber = 59` the result is `58`. Therefore the lower bound never converges to the upper bound.

Comment: Okay I see, I'm trying to think of what logic I should use but I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty solution for your program:

**Code**:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The number you're thinking of is " + new Program().play(0, 100));
    }

    public void instructions(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
        //xxx
    }

    public int play(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
        instructions(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            switch (upperLimit - lowerLimit) {
                case 0:
                    return lowerLimit;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Is your number " + upperLimit + "? (y/n)");
                    boolean upper = "y".equals(reader.nextLine());
                    return upper ? upperLimit : lowerLimit;
                default:
                    int x = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;
                    System.out.println("Is your number greater than " + x + "? (y/n)");
                    boolean greater = "y".equals(reader.nextLine());
                    if (greater) {
                        lowerLimit = x + 1;
                    } else {
                        upperLimit = x;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Is your number greater than 50? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 25? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 38? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 44? (y/n)
n
Is your number greater than 41? (y/n)
y
Is your number greater than 43? (y/n)
n
Is your number 43? (y/n)
n
The number you're thinking of is 42
```

Comment: You're hurting readability quite a lot by trying to do something different.